# Does Danger Sense make any spell/trap/effect seen be able to make a Dex saving throw with advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, class-feature, saving-throw, barbarian

Let's say I'm a Level 2 Barbarian and I'm targeted by the spell Shatter.

Since I have Danger Sense and I see the spell coming at me, and because specific beasts general I won't be making a constitution saving throw but rather a Dexterity Saving throw with advantage, is that it?

Answer (score 23):

Danger Sense does not replace the required save with Dexterity because it can be seen - and specifically it does not activate in the case of Shatter.

Danger Sense gives you (PHB, 48)

> Advantage on Dexterity Saving Throws against effects that you can see

Shatter is a Constitution Save and therefore Danger Sense doesn't apply. Danger Sense does NOT change the spell/effect's saving throw, it only gives you advantage IF it is a Dex save.

A specific example of where this would work is Fireball - which is a Dexterity Saving Throw.

Comment: I think you meant to say "does _NOT_" change the [...] saving throw"

Comment: I don't think there is any feature that changes the attribute used for a saving throw, is there?

Comment: @MarkCogan Some unearthed arcana options do (lore wizard, mystic).

Comment: @NautArch Pretty sure those options only change your proficiency in a given Save, not allow you to use a Dex for a Constitution save. I know the Mystic just allows you to swap Wis with any other save proficiency. Unless I missed something.

Comment: I'll have to double check all of those, but this comment discussion is pretty off topic and better suited for chat.

Comment: Loremaster Wizard can change a spell to have a different save entirely. That UA class allows for very interesting spell manipulation. Specifically: **"When you cast a spell with a spell slot and the
spell requires a saving throw, you can change the 
saving throw from one ability score to another of 
your choice."**